# Getting HP Envy touch display to work a bit better

Tags: mouse, hp, multi-touch, touchscreen

Currently I have an HP Envy with a touchscreen running Ubuntu. The touchscreen does work to some extent (I can click most things and drag selection boxes on the desktop) but it doesn't seem to want to let me do anything involving clicking and dragging besides that, like highlighting text or moving windows or scroll bars. It also seems completely unwilling to let me click on small things, like the up/down buttons on either end of scroll bars, or the close/minimize/maximize buttons on windows. 
I don't really mind if I can't scroll or use multi-finger gestures on this laptop the way I can on a tablet or phone, but I would like it if I could at least get the touchscreen working as well as a regular mouse or touchpad in terms of capability, and the complete inability to drag things or click small items is a bit of an issue on that score. 
Thanks in advance for any help I can get here!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was specific to XFCE installed under Ubuntu; now that I've switched back to Unity, there no longer seems to be any problem. 
Still not sure what it was or how to fix it, but it now no longer applies to me.